# RestFB - How to verify Application Id from received User Access Token

Tags: restfb

In RestFB, after getting Facebook Client Object through User access token

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken, VERSION_2_12);
```

How to verify the application Id for which the access token is issued?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need your app access token. Then make a debug call on it like this:

```
FacebookClient appFacebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(appToken, Version.VERSION_2_12);
DebugTokenInfo tokenInfo = appFacebookClient.debugToken(accessToken);
```

Afterwards, you check the content of the `tokenInfo` object.